# Get index of array item if item of array equals name

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of items like this:

```
{
  "dateAdded" : "2016-02-09 12:41:37",
  "customValue" : "5",
  "name" : "highestHeight"
},
{
  "dateAdded" : "2016-02-09 12:41:37",
  "customValue" : "46.91",
  "name" : "highestWeight"
},
{
  "dateAdded" : "2016-02-09 12:41:37",
  "customValue" : "14972.02",
  "name" : "highestScore"
},
```

I would like to get the items associated with the item that has the name = highestScore but not sure how or even what I should be searching for to find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about starting with the documentation on [Array](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html), which will show that it implements the [CollectionType](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs14CollectionType) protocol, which has a `filter` function:

```
myArray.filter({ $0.name == "highestScore" })
```

That assumes it is an array of objects/types, and not an array of Dictionary instances. If that was the case, then you would use:

```
myArray.filter({ $0["name"] == "highestScore" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at functional filtering here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/82599/swift-functional-programming-tutorial

Do something like:

```
highscoreArray= yourArray.filter { (dictionary) in dictionary["name"]! == "highestScore" }
```

Haven't tested it but it should be along of the lines of that.